# How is "⿰甴曱 ⿰曱甴" read?

Tags: pronunciation

I was scrolling through BabelStone's [PUA](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/PUA.html) page when I came across the following:

> [image]

For evidential purposes they also link the following picture:

> [image]

Unlike some entries on the chart there is no romanizaion for these two characters. Seeing "甴" makes me think it might be read something like "zou"/奏, but I really have no idea.

How is "⿰甴曱 ⿰曱甴" read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://read01.com/zh-hk/4DDkPPQ.html:

> 當詢問老闆，這個麵館為什麼要把店名取為「曱甴 (*sic*) 曱甴 面 館」時，老闆說這兩個字讀「Ga ga」，就是當地方言「肉」的意思。
>
> 通過公開資料顯示，老闆提到的「gǎ gǎ」實為「朒朒」。

Either the store owner made it up, or it's a very localised usage of those characters. The pronunciation is 「嘎嘎」 (「朒」 is a variant of 「嘎」), which is a colloquial Sichuanese word for *meat*.

Comment: Funnily enough 曱 does seem to be read `ga` in Chaozhou, Min'nan & Fuzhou. Sometimes 嘎 is use as an alternative for 曱, in Mandarin, as well. It would be interesting to see if there was some sort of influence from 湖广填川, perhaps where cockroach was the only source of meat for some locales.

Comment: What do you mean by "an alternative for 曱 in Mandarin"? I don't have many topolect resources `=(`, and from my limited search 曱 only appears in Cantonese. The etymological root of Cantonese 曱甴 appears to be 虼蚻 in the Min topolects.

Comment: ①https://amandahsu1118.pixnet.net/blog/post/337048004 是真的「嘎抓」（蟑螂）. ②https://www.zhihu.com/question/48020650 【甴曱】这两个字是广州蟑螂的粤语写法，普通话最接近的读音是“嘎砸”。

Answer (score 0):

甴 means "cockroach" in Cantonese. It is read as /zha2/ in Mandarin

曱 also means  "cockroach" in Cantonese, It is read as /ya1/ in Mandarin

(曱 and 甴 used only in combined form 曱甴.)

[曱甴](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/1330/)

> jyutping: gaat6 zaat6*2
>
> pinyin: **yue1 zha2**
>
> **cockroach** | Mand.: 蟑螂

Since I am Cantonese, I read 曱甴 as /gaat6 zaat6*2/. But I have never heard of "甴曱"

My guess is "曱甴 甴曱" is a type of noodle shaped like cockroach in  Guiyan

Comment: The (claimed) noodle name isn't 曱甴 甴曱 (which is 4 characters long), it's just two characters (each of which combines 曱 and 甴 into a single character). So it's still not clear what the pronunciations of these weird characters is, or is meant to be.

Comment: Yeah, "⿰甴曱" is one character & "⿰曱甴" is another.